# Sending http post request in buildbot

Tags: python, httprequest, buildbot

I am using buildbot version 0.8.5 and need to send an HTTP post request from it as a step. After searching for it on internet, I found that the latest version 0.8.8 has a step called HTTPStep for doing so. Is there any similar step in the older version?

I know it can be done using batch file or python program using urllib2. but is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `HTTPStep` from 0.8.8 (provided you install the necessary dependency (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/txrequests and http://python-requests.org/)). Just copy the [http.py](https://github.com/buildbot/buildbot/raw/master/master/buildbot/steps/http.py) file from 0.8.8 next to your `master.cfg`, and have your `master.cfg` import the `HTTPStep` derived class `POST` from module http instead of buildbot.steps.http.

Some small adjustments might be needed to make it work with the API of 0.8.5 though.

Answer (score -1):

Just my thoughts..As far as I know it is better to use a python script from a build step. Simple and easy to control. The logic being:

1. the entire buildbot is inside one http connection/session and sending another http request somewhere might have issues with the connection/session.
2. from the buildbot httpstep description, you need to install additional python packages which might be not be so convenient to do on multiple slaves/masters.